# Saving bi-directional relationship objects

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a problem to persist the entity Permission using Hibernate. I need to save many Permission objects, which has an attribute Group (Foreign key), but in the same time I am saving Permission, I am saving the Group, so I don't have a Group ID (Primary key) to set in Permission  object to make an association.

My relationship:

```
@Entity
@BatchSize(size = 10)
public class Group implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "grupo")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Permissao> permissoes;
}

@Entity
@BatchSize(size = 10)
public class Permission implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private Grupo grupo;
}
```

Stack:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [hemisphere-web] in context with path 
[/hemisphere-web] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient 
instance - save the transient instance before flushing: 
net.pontoall.hemisphere.core.model.Permission.grupo -> 
net.pontoall.hemisphere.core.model.Grupo; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object 
references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: 
net.pontoall.hemisphere.core.model.Permissao.grupo -> 
net.pontoall.hemisphere.core.model.Grupo] with root cause
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient 
instance - save the transient instance before flushing: 
net.pontoall.hemisphere.core.model.Permissao.grupo ->        net.pontoall.hemisphere.core.model.Grupo
```

Could someone give me a hint, please?

Comment: Show us your code, and the stack trace of the exception you get. You just need to save the group, the assign the group to the permission (and vice-versa), and save the permission.

Comment: Ok, I understand, are you suggesting that I do this in two steps?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you are working with JPA/Hibernate you are working with object. You don't need to set a group id to the permission object you just pass it the group instance.

Now according to your mapping you have a cascade on the permissions List in the group, so you should save the group and it should work fine.
If you'll try to save a permission without saving the group first then you'll probably get a TransientObjectException.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also use cascade from Permission to Group, in that way when you save a new Permission which belongs to a new Group, the Group will also be persisted:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Group group;
```